# How to clear data on kendo ui angular 2 grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm looking for a way to clear the Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2 if the user navigates another page or simply logout. I have tried clearing the observable to `null` and it is not good and i couldn't fill data after all. Can anyone suggest me a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the view to empty array using either `=Observable.empty()` or `=Observable.from([])` but you will need to rebind the service back again if you want to fetch data. This is why the easiest way will be to just call `.next([])` and then when needed fetch the data. See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SfsQuZvxGoypKsw7NdKT?p=preview)

Comment: I worked it out with empty method .But the problem is when i go to another route and come back again the same data exists in the grid how to clear the grid (e.g: logout and login)

Comment: use the approach that I shared, it should work in that scenario.

Comment: I can't use net method since it is not a valid method in my app.it doesn't exist so the only choice i had to make is from method.it is working but as i explained when routing back and forth the data still resides.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted @knikolov's answer to suit my purposes. Since I use an object to store grid settings, `.next([])` was giving me type warnings, so replacing it with `.next(null)` works.

Also, it helps to set the grid's `skip` property to `0` to reset the paging as well, in case the user was no longer on the first page of results.

```
gridReset(): void {
    this.dataService.next(null); // clears grid data
    this.gridSettings.Skip = 0; // resets paging
    // ...
}
```

given the grid:

```
<kendo-grid name="theGrid" 
            [data]="gridSettings.GridData | async"
            [skip]="gridSettings.Skip"
            [pageSize]="gridSettings.PageSize">
```

and declaring the settings object variable:

```
public gridSettings: GridSettings = {
    Skip: 0,
    PageSize: 10,
    GridData: this.dataService
};
```