# How can we clear kendo UI Grid for angular 2 when we change paging of grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

We had prepared one demo of Kendo UI Grid binding with angular 2. 
We had used Custom paging with pagesize of 250 in this demo.
When we move to the next page in Grid, the memory usage increses every time. 
At some point scrolling gets slower and application also gets crashed.
So is there any way to clear grid data when i move to next or pervious page?
Or any other way to get better performance in grid with large amount of pagesize more then 500.

we have also tried this.gridData.next([])  to clear grid data. But .next() funtion is not supporting for Observable.

Can please provide demo for it.

Following is the code we are using to bind grid and custom paging.

```
Code in app.module.ts file. 
public query(config: any): void {
    this.getTask(config)
        .subscribe(x => super.next(x));

}
private getTask(config: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('Skip', config.skip);
    params.set('Take', config.take);      

    this.http.get(`${this.TaskCount_URL}`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(result => this.total = result);

    return this.http.get(`${this.TaskDetail_URL}`, { search: params })
        .map(this.extractData)
        .map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
            data: response,
            total: this.total
        }));
}

Code in app.Component.ts file
public onNextClick(event: any) {
    this.skip = this.skip + 1000;
    this.gridData = this.service;
    this.service.query({ skip: this.skip, take: this.pageSize, sort: this.sort });
}
```

Comment: Is this similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140186/how-to-clear-data-on-kendo-ui-angular-2-grid

Comment: knikolov no, that is when navigating away from the grid, this question is when changing page of the grid

Answer (score 1):

Change your query function slightly.

From this.

```
public query(config: any): void {
    this.getTask(config)
        .subscribe(x => super.next(x));

}
```

To this.

```
public query(config: any): void {
    super.next(data: [], total: 0);    
    this.getTask(config)
        .subscribe(x => super.next(x));
}
```

This will set the grid to nothing while its waiting for the next page of data.
The other caveat is to make sure you never send an error to the Behaviour Subject. If you do, it will stop processing anything else. Best practice is probably along the lines for this.

```
public query(config: any): void {
    super.next(data: [], total: 0);    
    this.getTask(config)
        .subscribe(
            x => super.next(x),
            err => {
                //notify user of error some other way.
                alert("Error retrieving grid data");
                super.next(data: [], total: 0);
            }
        );
}
```